# Duplicate of the cmdletconfiguration: cmdletname repair-spsite

Tags: sharepoint-server

Getting this error when i start Sharepoint 2013 management shell.

*Duplicate of the cmdletconfiguration: cmdletname repair-spsite*

[image]

Googled without any result.

Anyone have idea?

Comment: Did you install Gary Lapointe extensions for sharepoint 2013 I started getting this after installing the Gary Lapointe extensions i think.

Answer (score 1):

This issue also causes the User Profile Synchronization service to not start on your SharePoint environment. Just uninstall Gary Lapointe web part.